# What is the main chatroom of this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

It seems that there is no official, permanently open chatroom in [the chatroom list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=buddhism.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here: [Buddhism -- General discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism)

People don't use it ... so it's repeatedly (automatically) "frozen" for a lack of activity; but I can unfreeze it whenever someone asks.

When people chat it's normally in a "room" spun off from a specific question or answer.

Comment: Hmm, you don't have a bot that post questions on that room to keep it open? I see many sites have that bot?

Comment: Would you point me to an example (of a question posted by a bot in a chat room)?

Comment: The [Meta Academia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-429/meta-academia) bot will post new meta posts on [the generic chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46297494#46297494) of [academia.se]

Comment: We have one of those bots. Looking at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism, the most recent time it was frozen was two days after the bot posted a meta-question, so I don't know, maybe that doesn't keep the room unfrozen. Perhaps it would be good "for the community" if there were an active chat room -- it is a feature of other SE sites -- hasn't taken off, here. Look through the history of the room if you like, it's been occasionally or in the distant past. People do chat still but individuals about specific topics in different rooms.

Comment: there is an anti-room-freeze bot. I've asked the author to add it to this site: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49127871#49127871